# How to filter special characters in json?

Tags: json

I use java generated json like this:

```
[{"nickname":"abc,def"},{"nickname":"abc'def"},{"nickname":"abc"def"}]
```

when I execute `eval()`, it raises exception.

I wanna keep comma and quotes in the json.

how to handle this kind of situation?

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: By `eval()`, are you referring to JavaScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an exception because your json in invalid! How did you generate it? In whatever language you use, build your data structure and call a json encode function (e.g. json_encode in PHP) to generate valid json.

In this specific example, you need to escape the double quote in the last string:

```
   [{"nickname":"abc,def"},{"nickname":"abc'def"},{"nickname":"abc\"def"}]
```

Note: using eval is not safe, you need to use JSON.parse()!

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle this situation by parsing JSON.

#### `eval()` does not parse JSON.

You need to call `JSON.parse()`, which does parse JSON and will work fine.

---

The other part of the solution is to generate valid JSON.
`"abc"def"` is not valid JSON.

You need to change your Java code to use an actual JSON library (such as gson or jackson) which will generate valid JSON.

Comment: The actual answer to the stated question is parentheses.